# Rails prints the query result along with the object data in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create a notebook app in rails. I need to print all the notes in the index view, so below is code in haml.

```
 = @notes.each do |note|
   %h1= link_to note.title, note
   %p= time_ago_in_words(note.created_at)
```

The problem is after the Note title and created time are displayed, the query result is printed at the end(Screenshot below).

[image]
The issue persists only while printing all the notes at once using loop. Can't figure out what's the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `=` with `-`

```
- @notes.each do |note|
```

If you just want to loop over `@notes` use `-` if you want to print some output use `=`

```
- @notes.each do |note|
   %h1= link_to note.title, note
   %p= time_ago_in_words(note.created_at)
```